# python numpy array padding issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding

I have a numpy array v with shape (1000, 68), v is supposed to padding to 100 dimension with 0s. As a result, the v's shape will be (1000, 100)

I tried to use the following approaches:

```
t = np.lib.pad(v, (16, 16), 'minimum') # numpy method

t = sequence.pad_sequences(v, maxlen = 100, padding = 'post') # Keras text processing method
```

Above two methods returned the t with correct shape (1000, 100), but each array t[n] (n from 0 to 99) is a zero vector [0, 0, 0, ....0]

Answer (score 1):

Following [numpy.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) documentation, I tried

```
np.pad(v, [(0,0), (16,16)], 'constant')
```

with the expected result: 16 columns of zeros added on the left, and 16 on the right.

Comment: I tried to use a for loop to pad each array literately, and it worked. But your method is faster.